Blender 4.1: Why do I strongly see the triangulation on the opposite side of the normals? (cycles)
I have a parametric surface in which for some reason I strongly see the triangulation on one side of the normals. How do I make this surface look fully smooth? I tried the subdivision and triangulation modifiers without too much success.


It turns out the Add more objects add-on seems to mesh both sides of XYZ functions (parametric surfaces) which caused this issue. It was resolved by just removing the faces on one side of the surface
